# Adding variables to file path in java

Tags: java, string, path

Is it possible to modify a file path so that it incorporates a String variable?

example code

```
String var = "Picture.jpg";
   ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Main\\Documents\\CompSciProjects\\Memory Game\\var");
```

Comment: `ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Main\\Documents\\CompSciProjects\\Memory Game\\" + var);`

Comment: omg I feel dumb, such an obvious answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
String var = "Picture.jpg";
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(String.format("C:\\Users\\Main\\Documents\\CompSciProjects\\Memory Game\\%s", var));
```